# Wordpress Custom SQL Query and Group Concat

Tags: php, sql, wordpress, group-concat

I am trying to run the below query to get the unique result of object_id.  I figured using Group_concat Distinst might work the best. I need to used the results of the query as a variable in the where clause of my next query.

The below query runs fine in flyspeedsql software, but I can't seem to see the results in php.

Is there a better way to approach this?

Is wordpress get_results the right function to use?

It should return something link 55,56,57

Also from the results of this query how do I set up a variable that could be used in the  where clause of my next query?

Query 1

```
      $query = ("Select
         Group_Concat(Distinct $wpdb->term_relationships.object_id)
      From
           $wpdb->term_taxonomy Inner Join
           $wpdb->term_relationships On $wpdb->term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id =
           $wpdb->term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id Inner Join
           $wpdb->terms On $wpdb->term_taxonomy.term_id = $wpdb->terms.term_id
       Where
           $wpdb->terms.name = 'Honda' And
           $wpdb->term_taxonomy.taxonomy = 'brands'");

       $results = $wpdb->get_results($query);
```

Comment: Are you wanting the IDs from your first table soley so you can use them for a query in your next table? Also, are you declaring `global $wpdb;` before using `$wpdb`?

Comment: @Mister Melancholy, yes I am using `global $wpdb;` before this statement.  I need the id's so that I can run another query that uses the ids as a criteria.  But I am unsure exactly the most efficient way to grab the ids for use in a criteria. Any thoughts?

Comment: Are you wanting to run a query that checks for those 3 IDs seperately, or will they be in one field? Table/database structure would be a giant help here.

Comment: Just one field something like `select * from  tblname where object_id=$value` The variable `$value` would be the object ids returned in the above query.

Comment: Oh, sorry about the late answer. I was tired lastnight and wanted to make sure I didn't do it wrong or something. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Have you heard of MYSQL [sub queries?](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/subqueries.html)

Honestly, I haven't read that whole article myself, but I know the concept well enough to do what you want with 1 query (though it'll be monstrous)

```
Select
     $wpdb->some_other_table.some_field
From
     $wpdb->some_other_table
Where
     $wpdb->some_other_table.some_other_field = (Select
       Group_Concat(Distinct $wpdb->term_relationships.object_id)
  From
       $wpdb->term_taxonomy Inner Join
       $wpdb->term_relationships On $wpdb->term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id =
       $wpdb->term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id Inner Join
       $wpdb->terms On $wpdb->term_taxonomy.term_id = $wpdb->terms.term_id
   Where
       $wpdb->terms.name = 'Honda' And
       $wpdb->term_taxonomy.taxonomy = 'brands');
```

I don't know if this'll fit your needs 100% because your description is rather vague, but I'm sure you can figure out how to make this work for you if it turns out being a solution.